# is there any way to redirect (like redirect_to) the url from worker, modules in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.3

Hi I am processing some background jobs and I need to redirect the URL from the module or directly from the worker but as per my knowledge, there is only one method i.e redirect_to but it's not available in module and worker as per the rails MVC architecture but I need to do this.

Please see below is my code:-

```
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(Figaro.env.fb_app_id,Figaro.env.fb_secret_token,Figaro.env.fb_callback_url)
oauth_code_url = @oauth.url_for_oauth_code
redirect_to oauth_code_url
```

I have also included the `include ActionController::UrlFor` to get the redirect_to method in Module and Worker but it's again throwing the error and I was not able to call controller methods into the module or worker. could anyone please suggest what would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: Redirect what? A worker is not running a browser request itself. Is the worker being invoked by the controller, and then the controller waiting for the worker to complete?

Comment: @FireLancer No my worker not involved by the controller. Actually, I have a callback URL and I want to hit that URL after that I will receive a client_code and then I need to send that client code to FB to get access token and this token will expire on certain interval of time so I need to run this task every time.

Answer (score 0):

Redirects only make sense inside the Request/Response cycle, workers usually happen on the background and asynchronously, so the user that might have initiated isn't waiting for the worker's response.

If you do want to wait (run the worker synchronously), it's not up to the worker to redirect, the worker should simply "signal" the controller to perform the redirect (this is because you want to keep a separation of concerns).

Comment: my worker not involved to the controller that's why I am facing this issue. the worker should simply "signal" the controller to perform the redirect ?? how a worker can signal the controller ?? If it is possible through module then I can also use a module and include that module inside worker?

Comment: If your controller is not involved, who exactly do you want to redirect? If there is no user waiting for the action to be performed, there is no one to redirect?

Comment: yes controller not involved, actually I need to generate a new token from server side so I have written code to refresh the token before it expires. and no user is waiting for it and the use of the redirect_to method is to just hit the callback URL because I have tried other lib like Net, HtttpClient etc they are sending the request and getting a response to the callback URL but the callback URL not called (coming back to my other controller action) but redirect_to doing fine.